# Is it possible to checkout Gitlab repository in YML which sits in Github?

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops, gitlab, yaml

So I'm trying to learn deployement with Azure Devops. I have this Angular app sitting in Gitlab which already has a CI/CD pipeline with jenkins to kubernetes cluster. So i was thinking to do the same with Azure Devops via YAML. Which is not possible according to [**Azure docs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/?view=azure-devops) directly from gitlab.

So what i'm trying to do is create CI pipeline from github which takes [`checkout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cyaml-example#checkout) from gitlab UI repo and build it for deployement.

I have created a `Repository Resource` in my below pipeline YAMl file. Azure give me error saying:

> `Repository JpiPipeline references endpoint https://gitlab.com/myusername/myUiRepo.git which does not exist or is not authorized for use`

```
trigger:
  - master


resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: UiPipeline.  #alias
    type: git
    name: repository_name
    # ref: refs/heads/master  # ref name to use; defaults to 'refs/heads/master'
    endpoint: https://@gitlab.com/myusername/myUiRepo.git   # <-- Is this possible


stages:
- stage: Checkout
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
    continueOnError: true
    steps:
    - checkout: JpiPipeline
    - script: echo "hello to my first Build"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repository type gitlab is not support in YAML pipeline yet. The currently supported types are git, github, and bitbucket, see [supported types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#type).

The workaround to get the gitlab repo sources is to run git command inside the script tasks.

For below example Yaml pipeline:

`- checkout: none` to avoid checkout the github source.

Use `git clone  https://username:password@gitlab.com/useraccount/reponame.git` to clone the gitlab repo inside a script task.

```
stages:
- stage: Checkout
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    pool: 
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - script: | 
        git clean -ffdx
        git clone  https://username:password@gitlab.com/useraccount/reponame.git
         #if your password or username contain @ replace it with %40
```

Your gitlab repo will be clone to folder  `$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)/reponame`

Another workaround is to classic UI pipeline. Gitlab repo type is supported in Classic UI pipeline.

You can choose `Use the classic editor` to create a classic ui pipeline.

[image]

When you come to select source page. Choose **other git** and click `Add connection` to add your gitlab repo url. Then the pipeline will get the sources for your gitlab repo.

[image]

Comment: Looks promising, let me try and get back to you.

Comment: so i get error `/azure-pipelines.yml: (Line: 14, Col: 12, Idx: 251) - (Line: 14, Col: 12, Idx: 251): Mapping values are not allowed in this context.`

For  line 14, i have updated the question with yml corresponding to lines.

Comment: Hi @ans2human It seems your yaml file is not in well format. Please make sure there is no indentation error in your yaml file. I found my above yaml example has an indentation error during copying and pasting. I have correct the bad indentation for above yaml file.

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thanks a ton, @levi. Say if i want to use 2 seperate branches from the same repo should i clone both of branches seperately or somehow i can checkout from the initial clone and work with them.